# Formatted USB now shows as a disk drive

Tags: windows-10, usb, partitioning, usb-flash-drive

About a year back i bought a USB from Asda that of which the manufacture is unknown. i made it a bootable USB for kali linux and done the install to a separate USB. i decide to format it as i could use it for other things, so i use admin EaseUS to wipe it, while later it fails so i unplug it an plug it back in. Next thing i know i try to open it in files and it says "Please insert disk" ive had a look in disk management it comes up as:

"

Disk 1
Removable (E:)

No media

"

[disk management screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soxoh.png)

By this point i don't know what do do so... can u guys help?

Comment: Using a hex editor (HxD or similar) in Disk Mode, can you access the device or does it show up with 0 sectors? Since you seem to be familiar with Linux, how does it appear under Linux? use parted or gparted to see if the device can be accessed. If so, create a new partition table and a partition, you don’t have to format it, as windows might be happy with the presence of a partition table and offer to format it by itself... Just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have come to the conclusion that the disk is dead as i have gotten nowhere and no app can detect it (except for files) thanks though for the help, i do appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be caused by the lack of a partition, which can happen when your USB was used to boot and then wiped.

The diskpart command in Windows command prompt can be used to create a partition. The following guide was taken from:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200124(v=ws.11).aspx

Note this method works equally well to create a bootable USB:

1. Insert a USB flash drive into a running computer
2. Open a Command Prompt window as an administrator.
3. Type `diskpart`
4. In the new command line window that opens, to determine the USB flash drive number or drive letter, at the command prompt, type `list disk`, and then click ENTER. The list disk command displays all the disks on the computer. Note the drive number or drive letter of the USB flash drive
5. At the command prompt, type `select disk X`, where X is the drive number or drive letter of the USB flash drive, and then click ENTER.
6. Type `clean`, and the click ENTER. This command deletes all data from the USB flash drive.
7. To create a new primary partition on the USB flash drive, type `create part pri`, and then click ENTER
8. To select the partition that you just created, type `select part 1`, and then click ENTER.
9. To format the partition, type `format fs=ntfs quick`, and then click ENTER.
10. Type `active`, and then click ENTER.
11. Type `exit`, and then click ENTER.

Comment: lack of partition usually doesn’t manifest as shown in the image from the disk management. diskpart is worth a try, but if the sector amount is reported to be zero, this doesn’t work. Hence my question if the situation under Linux is different (what makes Windows think this is a device with a missing medium may not trigger the same code in Linux, and the drive size might still be reported correctly)

Comment: @george tian i tried that it gave me a output of "No usable free extent could be found. It may be that there is insufficient
free space to create a partition at the specified size and offset. Specify
different size and offset values or don't specify either to create the
maximum sized partition. It may be that the disk is partitioned using the MBR disk
partitioning format and the disk contains either 4 primary partitions, (no
more partitions may be created), or 3 primary partitions and one extended
partition, (only logical drives may be created)." on step 7

Comment: @Ro-ee ill give linux a try i have a totally separate PC to do it on (rpi) and ill get back to you if it works

Comment: @Ro-ee i tried Gparted and it failed to pick it up

Comment: what does linux say about the device, esp. output from 'dmesg' after the device has been plugged? Ideally, it should show the device detected, and the number of logical blocks (and their size), as well as the type (perferrably USB mass storage device).

Comment: @Ro-ee lnux doesn't output anything i diddn't try dmsg but it wasn't even showing up in files

Answer (score 0):

You say you used the disk to boot a Kali Linux installer, but you don't say how you prepared that installer. This is a critical detail, since some methods (such as using `dd` to write the `.iso` file directly to the USB drive) create a sort of Frankenstein's Monster of disk formats that's likely to create problems in the future if it's not properly erased. Going on the assumption (which may well be incorrect) that this is what's happened, the trick is to completely wipe those bogus data structures. A couple ways to do this in Linux are:

- **`sgdisk`** -- Type `sgdisk -Z /dev/sdc` (changing `/dev/sdc` to whatever the proper device identifier is). This uses `sgdisk`'s ability to erase all the GPT data structures, which will also wipe enough of anything else that the disk should become much less confusing to other tools.
- **`dd`** -- You can *completely* wipe the disk with `dd`, as in `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc`. (Again, change `/dev/sdc` as appropriate.) This operation will take several minutes to complete, but it does a very thorough job -- every sector will end up containing nothing but "0" values. You may be able to get away with wiping just the first few sectors by adding `bs=512 count=100` to the `dd` command. This will do the job much more quickly, but it will be less thorough and so you might still have problems.

In either case, the disk will be left in an unpartitioned state when done, so you'll need to create a filesystem on the disk, and perhaps re-partition it. You can use a tool like GParted in Linux or EaseUS in Windows to do both operations at once, or do them separately with smaller Linux tools -- use `parted`, `gdisk`, or `fdisk` to partition and then use `mkfs` to create a filesystem on the partition. Creating a "raw" filesystem on the whole disk without first partitioning it is reasonable for some use cases; Windows ignores everything but the first partition on USB flash drives, so there's not much point to creating partitions if the disk will be used exclusively from Windows.

If wiping the disk in this way doesn't help, then it could be that it's failed or was defective from the start (despite the fact that you used it successfully for a while). Some cheap "generic" USB drives are configured to *look like* they're bigger than they are. They work for a while when you store just a few files on them, but when you try to use their full capacity, they flake out and may become completely useless. It could be you've hit that wall with your drive. If so, consider this a lesson on [caveat emptor.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caveat_emptor) Likewise, even good USB drives eventually fail. If yours is older (or if it's new but defective or low in quality) it may have hit this point.

Comment: i tried that, linux does not read it at all, Windows piks it up but EaseUS fails to pick it up, although when i plug it in Ease Us re scans devices so i does see the drive just it does not show it. Also i used "win32 disk imager"

Comment: If by "linux does not read it at all" you mean that you see no new `/dev/sd{x}` device when you plug the disk in, then chances are the disk is dead (or maybe you've got some flaky USB hardware in your computer). If you're relying on GUI tools in Linux, don't. In Linux, text-mode tools are much better for this sort of diagnostic process.